# Convert float -> double -> float

Tags: c#, floating-point

Is it possible to convert float to double, then back without losing precision? I mean first float should be exaclty bit by bit same like result float.

Comment: They have both their own precision, whereby you may convert one to the other, but not vice-versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and we can test it:

```
float fl = float.NegativeInfinity;

long cycles = 0;

while (true)
{
    double dbl = fl;
    float fl2 = (float)dbl;

    int flToInt1 = new Ieee754.Int32SingleConverter { Single = fl }.Int32;
    int flToInt2 = new Ieee754.Int32SingleConverter { Single = fl2 }.Int32;

    if (flToInt1 != flToInt2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nDifferent: {0} (Int32: {1}, {2})", fl, flToInt1, flToInt2);
    }

    if (fl == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n0, Sign: {0}", flToInt1 < 0 ? "-" : "+");
    }

    if (fl == float.PositiveInfinity)
    {
        fl = float.NaN;
    }
    else if (float.IsNaN(fl))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        fl = Ieee754.NextSingle(fl);
    }

    cycles++;

    if (cycles % 100000000 == 0)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\nDone");
Console.ReadKey();
```

and the utility classes:

```
public static class Ieee754
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct Int32SingleConverter
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int Int32;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public float Single;
    }

    public static float NextSingle(float value)
    {
        int bits = new Int32SingleConverter { Single = value }.Int32;

        if (bits >= 0)
        {
            bits++;
        }
        else if (bits != int.MinValue)
        {
            bits--;
        }
        else
        {
            bits = 0;
        }

        return new Int32SingleConverter { Int32 = bits }.Single;
    }
}
```

On my computer, in Release Mode, without the debugger (Ctrl+F5 from Visual Studio), it is around 2 minutes.

There are around 4 billion different `float` values. I cast them around and convert them to `int` to binary check them. Note that `NaN` values are "particular". The IEEE754 standard has multiple values for `NaN`, but .NET "compresses" them to a single `NaN` value. So you could create a `NaN` value (manually, through bit manipulation) that wouldn't be converted back and forth correctly. The "standard" `NaN` values is converted correctly, so are `PositiveInfinity` and `NegativeInfinity`, `+0` and `-0`.

Comment: I was thinking about writing something like this :) Big thanks.

Comment: @zgnilec The "interesting" part is how to find the "next" float after a float. It can be useful if you want to know the "distance" between floats (I already had the `Ieee754` class around... I had written it one year ago when I was experimenting with IEEE754)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as every float can be exactly represented as a double, the round trip will give you the exact value that you started with.

There is one possible technical exception to your requirement that they are bit-by-bit the same: there are multiple bit patterns that correspond to NaN values (this is often referred to as the "NaN payload"). As far as I know, there is no strict requirement that this be preserved: you will still get a NaN, just maybe a slightly different one.